# prop() takes too long

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<select>` element displaying values from a big database. Using jQuery I need to select the relevant items. The problem is that when I have large amount items to select, about 60,000, the time that `$(options2select).prop('selected',true)`, can take too long, about 50 seconds!

Note: I used the `attr()` method before, but read somewhere that `prop()` is faster, and it's not!

I'm searching for a way to optimize this task but I can't find any. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your issue is not with `prop`, but having a frankly ridiculous number of items in your `select` list. JS is never going to be quick in that situation. I would strongly suggest reducing that list somehow.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Not so much *JavaScript*, as the DOM and browser. JavaScript can readily process 60k things right quick like.

Comment: What's `options2select`? An array? A selector?

Comment: option2select is an array. BTW, it takes less than a second to iterate this array, but trying to use prop() on each element is what consuming the time.

Comment: Is using [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) maybe a clever alternative..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

60,000 options in `select` lists in a browser is not going to be workable on several levels, not least user experience. It's just always going to be slow and awkward, not to mention incomprehensible to the user. So the best thing to do here is to not do that, to put things into categories, etc., etc.

Answering the actual question, though:

1. Assuming `options2select` is an array (since you haven't said what it is), this would probably be faster:

   ```
   options2select.forEach(function(option) {
       option.selected = true;
   });
   ```

   or even

   ```
   var n;
   for (n = options2select.length - 1; n >= 0; --n) {
       options2select[n].selected = true;
   }
   ```
2. Assuming `options2select` is a selector, much the same with `document.querySelectorAll` at the outset:

   ```
   var list = document.querySelectorAll(options2select);
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(option) {
       option.selected = true;
   });
   ```

   or even

   ```
   var list = document.querySelectorAll(options2select);
   var n;
   for (n = list.length - 1; n >= 0; --n) {
       list[n].selected = true;
   }
   ```

But again, *faster* doesn't mean *fast*.

Comment: I already categorized the data to 3 levels. School-Class-Student each in its own `select`.
its like 1-N relationship, means on school have multiple class, and one class have multiple student.
when a user choose all schools, and all classes, it cause the student `select` to be large

Comment: @YyYo: That doesn't change the fact that 60k options in a select list is just not workable.

Comment: I will try to find a way to categorize it with another level. Thx anyway